# How do you interpret this "typedef myType_t (*SpecialFunction_t)( void * );"

Tags: pointers, typedef, void

I understand myType_t is a type just like char or uint32 etc., 
Whats confusing is it has a pointer in front of Special function.

Analogous to int* SpecialFunction so you can pass a reference to this new variable SpecialFucntion.

What is the (void *) afterwards and why are both the (*SpecialFunction) and (void *) in separate brackets.

Comment: Add the language tag, C or C++ or ...?

Answer (score 1):

It's a pointer to a function.

That typedef makes it possible to write:
`SpecialFunction_t func;`

and have the compiler interpret it like:
`myType_t (*func) (void *);`

Comment: `myType_t (*func) (void *)` so `myType_t` is the typedefine `*SpecialFunction_t` is the pointer to the function and `void *` is another pointer of type void

Comment: Please read up on pointers to functions. In this case you could define a function `f` like this: `myType_t f(void *ptr) { return (myType_t)0; }`, take a reference to it like this: `SpecialFunction_t func = f;`, then dereference and invoke the original function like this: `myType_t result = func(NULL);`.

Comment: That makes more sense when there is a use case of such a function. Thanks